# 'much better' spoken rather than written English?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to use in a publication, that something is (a) 'much better' way of doing something?

Comment: Why do you think it might be wrong? Explaining that would be a much better way of framing the question than what you have done.

Comment: Seems like general reference to me.

Comment: I suggest you ask instead whether "much better" is appropriate in a formal written style.  It's not a question of grammar, nor strictly of spoken versus written language--many publications use relatively informal language.  But if you did ask this, it might be better if you gave an example context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

Writing or speaking, simple words can be **much better** than complex ones. They are more accessible, more readily understood, and less at risk of seeming pretentious.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong, but here's what I would do:

- verbal: much better, slightly better
- written: significantly better, marginally better

Answer (score -2):

*Better* is a comparative degree of *good* and *best*... Then why is it necessary to use *much*? *Better* says all... Then why should it be included redundantly?

Comment: Better is more that good, however sometimes we need to quantify that also relatively. Like much better, somewhat better etc